# Is there a more efficient to perform this matrix operation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to make the following thing in Matlab: given a matrix H, I want to build a matrix H* of same size such that H*(:,i) is the sum of the next columns (i.e. i+1 -> n) of H. So for example, if H is

```
H =

 2     4     7    14
 3     5    11    -3
```

I am expecting H* to be

```
25    21    14     0
13     8    -3     0
```

So far, I have done the following piece of code but it involves a `for` loop, so I am not expecting it to be very efficient (especially, my matrix will have a big number of columns in the practical application I will use).

```
H_tilde=zeros(size(H));
for i=1:size(H,2)
    H_tilde(:,i)=sum(H(:,i+1:size(H,2)),2);
end
```

Is there a way to make it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) along the 2nd dimension with the `'reverse'` option, as follows:

```
H_tilde = [cumsum(H(:, 2:end), 2, 'reverse') zeros(size(H,1), 1)];
```